# Tornado eventloop raising a "NoneType object is not iterable" when yielding multiple gen.Task

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to use the tornado event loop to do a series of tasks in parallel.
So I'm creating an event loop and creating a method, decorated by @gen.coroutine which yields a list of gen.Task calls to another method.

```
from tornado import ioloop, gen

class MyClass(object):                                           
@gen.coroutine                                               
def echo(text):                                              
    print text                                               
    return gen.Return()                                      

@gen.coroutine                                               
def send_messages(self, number):                             
    yield [gen.Task(self.echo, x) for x in xrange(number)]   
    self.loop.stop()                                         

def __init__(self):                                          
    self.loop = ioloop.IOLoop()                              
    self.loop.add_callback(self.send_messages, 3)            
    self.loop.start()                                        

MyClass()
```

It seems okay to me but doesn't work. When I run this I get a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error in tornado/concurrent.py.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

---

To help debug, I found that putting a pdb somewhere in the send_messages() method and doing self._echo("test").result() helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function signature is wrong so is mucking up the `functools.partial` binding:

```
@gen.coroutine                                               
def echo(text):      # <----- MISSING self                                 
    print text                                               
    return gen.Return()
```

Add the `self` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the [Return](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.Return) exception.

```
class MyClass(object):                                           
    @gen.coroutine                                               
    def echo(text):                                              
        print text                                               
        raise gen.Return()
```

Comment: in this case it works even if I don't raise / return anything, but yeah that's right I would need to raise it otherwise. Thanks!